# Gekko optimization package and numpy inverse function

Tags: python, numpy, ipopt, gekko

I am using Gekko for selecting A-optimal experiments for a set of reaction kinetics. The objective function is to minimize the trace(inv(Z'Z)) where Z is a scale sensitivity matrix computed by linearizing the ODEs around its parameters. As you can see the objective function involve the inverse of Z'Z. I used the numpy (and even scipy) inverse function and I run to the following error: "No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc inv"

I really don't know what's wrong. Without the inverse function, the optimizer works fine. Please, and Please help me. I am stuck with this problem over two weeks.

the code is included below:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

m = GEKKO()

# setting up the paraemter values
k = [2.11, 8.229, 0.0034, 0.000000000001, 4.1233e-05, 3.798835e-05, 0.0000000001]

k1f = k[0] # Var(bounds=(0,1))
Keq = k[1] # Var(bounds=(0,20))
k2 = k[2] # Var(bounds=(0,0.1)) 
k3 = k[3] # Var(bounds=(0,0.01)) 
k4 = k[4] # Var(bounds=(0,0.0001)) 
k5 = k[5] # Var(bounds=(0,0.0001)) 
k6 = k[6] # Var(bounds=(0,0.0001)) 

# Seting up the reaction time for 6hr
m.time = np.linspace(0,21600)
t = m.Param(value=m.time)

# The decision variable is the inital condition for te component SM1
SM1_0 = m.MV(value=1.0,lb=0.1,ub=100.0)
SM1_0.STATUS = 1

# Setting up the State variables
SM1 = m.Var(value=SM1_0)
D = m.Var(value=0.05)
SM2 = m.Var(value= 1.15)
P = m.Var(value=0.0)
SM1D = m.Var(value=0.0)
H2O = m.Var(value=0.3*595.7/(18.0*100.0))
I1 = m.Var(value=0.0)
I2 = m.Var(value=0.0)
I3 = m.Var(value=0.0)
I4 = m.Var(value=0.0)

# Defining the ODES
m.Equation(SM1.dt() ==  - k1f * SM1 * D + (k1f/Keq) * SM1D - k4 * SM1 * H2O)
m.Equation(D.dt() ==  -k1f * SM1 * D + (k1f/Keq) * SM1D + k2 * SM2 * SM1D - k5 * D * H2O)
m.Equation(SM2.dt() == - k2 * SM2 * SM1D - k3 * SM2 * P)
m.Equation(P.dt() == k2 * SM2 * SM1D - k3 * SM2 * P - k6 * P)
m.Equation(SM1D.dt() == k1f * SM1* D - (k1f/Keq)  * SM1D - k2 * SM2 * SM1D)
m.Equation(H2O.dt() == -k4 * SM1 * H2O - k5 * D * H2O)
m.Equation(I1.dt() == k3 * SM2 * P)
m.Equation(I2.dt() == k4 * SM1 * H2O)
m.Equation(I3.dt() == k5 * D * H2O)
m.Equation(I4.dt() == k6 * P)

# Defining the parameteric sensitivites
S_SM1k1f = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Dk1f = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_SM2k1f = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Pk1f = m.Var(value=0.0)
#    
S_SM1Keq = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_DKeq = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_SM2Keq = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_PKeq = m.Var(value=0.0)
#    
#        
S_SM1k2 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Dk2 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_SM2k2 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Pk2 = m.Var(value=0.0)

S_SM1k3 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Dk3 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_SM2k3 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Pk3 = m.Var(value=0.0)

S_SM1k4 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Dk4 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_SM2k4 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Pk4 = m.Var(value=0.0)

S_SM1k5 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Dk5 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_SM2k5 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Pk5 = m.Var(value=0.0)

S_SM1k6 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Dk6 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_SM2k6 = m.Var(value=0.0)
S_Pk6 = m.Var(value=0.0)


m.Equation(S_SM1k1f.dt() == -(k1f*D + k4*H2O)*S_SM1k1f - k1f*SM1 * S_Dk1f-SM1*D + SM1D/Keq)

m.Equation(S_Dk1f.dt()==-k1f*D *S_SM1k1f - (k1f*SM1+k5*H2O) * S_Dk1f+ k2*SM1D*S_SM2k1f-SM1*D + SM1D/Keq)

m.Equation(S_SM2k1f.dt() == -(k2*SM1D+ k3*P)*S_SM2k1f - k3*SM2*S_Pk1f)

m.Equation(S_Pk1f.dt() == (k2*SM1D- k3*P)*S_SM2k1f - k3*SM2*S_Pk1f- k6* S_Pk1f)


m.Equation(S_SM1Keq.dt() == -(k1f*D + k4*H2O)*S_SM1Keq - k1f*SM1 * S_DKeq - SM1D/(Keq)**2)

m.Equation(S_DKeq.dt() == -k1f*D *S_SM1Keq - (k1f*SM1+k5*H2O) * S_DKeq+ k2*SM1D*S_SM2Keq- SM1D/Keq**2)

m.Equation(S_SM2Keq.dt() == -(k2*SM1D+ k3*P)*S_SM2Keq - k3*SM2*S_PKeq)

m.Equation(S_PKeq.dt() == (k2*SM1D- k3*P)*S_SM2Keq - k3*SM2*S_PKeq- k6* S_PKeq)


m.Equation(S_SM1k2.dt() == -(k1f*D + k4*H2O)*S_SM1k2 - k1f*SM1 * S_Dk2 )

m.Equation(S_Dk2.dt() == -k1f*D *S_SM1k2 - (k1f*SM1+k5*H2O) * S_Dk2+ k2*SM1D*S_SM2k2 + SM2* SM1D)

m.Equation(S_SM2k2.dt() == -(k2*SM1D+ k3*P)*S_SM2k2 - k3*SM2*S_Pk2-SM2*SM1D)

m.Equation(S_Pk2.dt() == (k2*SM1D- k3*P)*S_SM2k2 - k3*SM2*S_Pk2- k6* S_Pk2+ SM2*SM1D)


m.Equation(S_SM1k3.dt() == -(k1f*D + k4*H2O)*S_SM1k3 - k1f*SM1 * S_Dk3 )

m.Equation(S_Dk3.dt() == -k1f*D *S_SM1k3 - (k1f*SM1+k5*H2O) * S_Dk3+ k2*SM1D*S_SM2k3 )

m.Equation(S_SM2k3.dt() == -(k2*SM1D+ k3*P)*S_SM2k3 - k3*SM2*S_Pk3-SM2*P)

m.Equation(S_Pk3.dt() == (k2*SM1D- k3*P)*S_SM2k3 - k3*SM2*S_Pk3- k6* S_Pk3- SM2*P)


m.Equation(S_SM1k4.dt() == -(k1f*D + k4*H2O)*S_SM1k4 - k1f*SM1 * S_Dk4 -SM1*H2O)

m.Equation(S_Dk4.dt() == -k1f*D *S_SM1k4 - (k1f*SM1+k5*H2O) * S_Dk4+ k2*SM1D*S_SM2k4)

m.Equation(S_SM2k4.dt() == -(k2*SM1D+ k3*P)*S_SM2k4 - k3*SM2*S_Pk4)

m.Equation(S_Pk4.dt() == (k2*SM1D- k3*P)*S_SM2k4 - k3*SM2*S_Pk4- k6* S_Pk4)


m.Equation(S_SM1k5.dt() == -(k1f*D + k4*H2O)*S_SM1k5 - k1f*SM1 * S_Dk5 )

m.Equation(S_Dk5.dt() == -k1f*D *S_SM1k5 - (k1f*SM1+k5*H2O) * S_Dk5+ k2*SM1D*S_SM2k5-D*H2O)

m.Equation(S_SM2k5.dt() == -(k2*SM1D+ k3*P)*S_SM2k5 - k3*SM2*S_Pk5)

m.Equation(S_Pk5.dt() == (k2*SM1D- k3*P)*S_SM2k5 - k3*SM2*S_Pk5- k6* S_Pk5)


m.Equation(S_SM1k6.dt() == -(k1f*D + k4*H2O)*S_SM1k6 - k1f*SM1 * S_Dk6 )

m.Equation(S_Dk6.dt() == -k1f*D *S_SM1k6 - (k1f*SM1+k5*H2O) * S_Dk6+ k2*SM1D*S_SM2k6)

m.Equation(S_SM2k6.dt() == -(k2*SM1D+ k3*P)*S_SM2k6 - k3*SM2*S_Pk6)

m.Equation(S_Pk6.dt() == (k2*SM1D- k3*P)*S_SM2k6 - k3*SM2*S_Pk6- k6* S_Pk6-P)


# defining the Z matrix(Scaled senisitivity matrix)
sk = 5.0*np.array(k)/2.0 # scaling factor for parameters
sy2 = np.array([0.048,0.00021,0.052,0.05]) # scaling factors for measurments

dSM1dk = np.matrix(np.transpose([S_SM1k1f*sk[0], S_SM1Keq*sk[1], S_SM1k2*sk[2], S_SM1k3*sk[3], S_SM1k4*sk[4], S_SM1k5*sk[5], S_SM1k6*sk[6]]))/np.sqrt(sy2[0])
dDdk   = np.matrix(np.transpose([S_Dk1f*sk[0],S_DKeq*sk[1],S_Dk2*sk[2],S_Dk3*sk[3],S_Dk4*sk[4],S_Dk5*sk[5],S_Dk6*sk[6]]))/np.sqrt(sy2[1])
dSM2dk = np.matrix(np.transpose([S_SM2k1f*sk[0], S_SM2Keq*sk[1], S_SM2k2*sk[2], S_SM2k3*sk[3], S_SM2k4*sk[4], S_SM2k5*sk[5], S_SM2k6*sk[6]]))/np.sqrt(sy2[2])
dPdk   = np.matrix(np.transpose([S_Pk1f*sk[0],   S_PKeq*sk[1],   S_Pk2*sk[2],   S_Pk3*sk[3],   S_Pk4*sk[4],   S_Pk5*sk[5],   S_Pk6*sk[6]]))/np.sqrt(sy2[3])

Z = np.vstack((dSM1dk,dDdk,dSM2dk,dPdk))

# definging the objecitve function as trace(inv(Z'Z))
m.Obj(np.trace((np.linalg.inv(np.dot(np.transpose(Z),Z)))))


m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve()
```

Answer (score 2):

Ali,

It looks like you will not be able to use the `np.inv` in your model. This is because the solver needs to have the first and second gradients of your model in order to solve and these are not readily available for external functions. This is the reason why many common functions like `np.sqrt` are replaced with Gekko-specific methods like `m.sqrt` in GEKKO.

I would recommend trying to find a way to replace `np.inv` in your model with something else. If this is a method that should be added to GEKKO then consider making a feature request on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO).